# BASH - combine .md files from subdirectories into a master .md

Tags: linux, macos, bash, pandoc

We have a growing list of subdirectories and we would like to summarize the content in each with a .txt or .md file. We would then like to consolidate those readmes into a single master readme. We have to run this process periodically as the contents of the subdirs updates (their individual readmes will be manually updated).

Is there set of commands that we can pipe in linux/macOS that we can use to read the subs (the file names change over time) and, say, use something like Pandoc to create the "master" readme?

The filename of the readme in the subdirs will be identical.

Comment: I suggest to [edit] the question and show an example of a few directories with `.md` files, the content of these files and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I create fake files to have a tree structure like yours:

```
Laptop:abc root$ mkdir 123
Laptop:abc root$ mkdir 456
Laptop:abc root$ mkdir 789
Laptop:abc root$ 
Laptop:abc root$ echo "lala 123" > 123/0.md
Laptop:abc root$ echo "lala 456" > 456/0.md
Laptop:abc root$ echo "lala 789" > 789/0.md
Laptop:abc root$ 
Laptop:abc root$ cat 123/0.md 
lala 123
```

And now we can display the entire content of each file in each subdirectory:

```
Laptop:abc root$ cat */*.md
lala 123
lala 456
lala 789
```

And here is the command to put the result in a file called master.md :

```
Laptop:abc root$ cat */*.md > master.md
```

We can now check the contents of the master.md file:

```
Laptop:abc root$ cat master.md 
lala 123
lala 456
lala 789
```